# Troubleshooting NFS mount RPC timeout issue

Tags: linux, networking, centos, nfs, mount

I have a NFS server up and running on `10.77.123.50`. However, I get a RPC timeout when I try to mount this server.

**Background**: Both server and client are on CentOS 7.4.1708. `iptables` is stopped on both machines. The `/etc/hosts.*` files on both machines are empty.

**Step 1 (from client)**: `showmount -e 10.77.123.50`

```
rpc mount export: RPC: Timed out
```

**Step 2 (from client)**:  I see that my `rpcbind` and `nfs` services are working fine on their own with `systemctl status {rpcbind,nfs}`.

**Step 3 (from client)**: `rpcinfo -p 10.77.123.50`

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  45198  status
    100024    1   tcp  57197  status
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  51317  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  51317  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  51317  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  33107  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  33107  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  33107  nlockmgr
```

**Step 4 (from client)**: I am able to reach the server and telnet to both of its NFS ports.

```
# ping 10.77.123.50
PING 10.77.123.50 (10.77.123.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.77.123.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms

# telnet 10.77.217.50 111
Trying 10.77.217.50...
Connected to 10.77.217.50.

# telnet 10.77.123.50 2049
Trying 10.77.123.50...
Connected to 10.77.123.50.
```

**Step 5 (from server)**: `tcpdump -i $INTERFACE host 10.77.123` I see packets incoming from the client via random ports (e.g. `59295`, `57291`, `40146`, `49933`) and outgoing to the client from the server's `.mountd`, `.sunrpc` and `.nfs` ports. Here's an example over a 3 second time range with 105 packets:

```
# first 9 packets

IP server.nfs > client.59295: Flags [P.], seq 1:29, ack 45, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 3265431829 ecr 10092752], length 28: NFS reply xid 1018070416 reply ok 24 null
IP client.59295 > server.nfs: Flags [.], ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10092752 ecr 3265431829], length 0
IP client.59295 > server.nfs: Flags [F.], seq 45, ack 29, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10092752 ecr 3265431829], length 0
IP server.nfs > client.59295: Flags [F.], seq 29, ack 46, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 3265431829 ecr 10092752], length 0
IP client.59295 > server.nfs: Flags [.], ack 30, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10092752 ecr 3265431829], length 0
IP client.57291 > server.sunrpc: UDP, length 56
IP server.sunrpc > client.57291: UDP, length 28
IP client.40146 > server.mountd: UDP, length 40
IP server.mountd > client.48400: Flags [.], ack 46, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 3265431868 ecr 10092752], length 0

# last 7 packets

IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [S], seq 1812867745, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 10095756 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP server.mountd > client.49933: Flags [S.], seq 2225809285, ack 1812867746, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3265434833 ecr 10095756,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10095756 ecr 3265434833], length 0
IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10095756 ecr 3265434833], length 44
IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10095957 ecr 3265434833], length 44
IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10096161 ecr 3265434833], length 44
IP client.49933 > server.mountd: Flags [P.], seq 1:45, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 10096570 ecr 3265434833], length 44
```

I don't know what I can diagnose from the above `tcpdump`. What else can I do to troubleshoot my issue?

Comment: Appears to be partially solved - tcpdump shows random src ports from the server's perspective. Using NFS v4 forces broadcast/listen on fixed ports - still getting a RPC timeout with `showmount -e` but I'm able to mount the volume with NFS v4.